# How to convert Android OpenGL ES 2.0 triangle sample to points

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I was using this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html)
and got it working but I wanted to only draw the points of the triangle. When I set the mode in drawArrays from GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES to GLES20.GL_POINTS nothing is drawn. Alternatively just setting the point size in the vertex shader also draws nothing. What am I missing?

Looking at code like this [this](http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/source/browse/trunk/Android/Ch13_ParticleSystem/src/com/openglesbook/particlesystem/ParticleSystemRenderer.java?r=49)
 I'm not sure what I would need since I don't want to use a texture unless I have to.

Answer (score 0):

"[Simple OpenGL Primitives](http://www.authenticsociety.com/about/OpenGL_Primitives_glVertex)" says:

> Points can make excellent particle effects such as sparks, or dust
>   particles glimmering as they pass through the rays of light. Even
>   though we are working with 3D graphics, rendering a single point on
>   the screen by itself ***creates an illusion of 2D space***, because our
>   monitor screens are flat, or 2-dimensional and there is nothing to
>   indicate depth. Therefore, one way to make points seem interactive is
>   to have them move on the screen in interesting patterns such as
>   ***circles, spirals and variations of the sine and cosine formulas***.

**Edit**:
But if you only want that **your points be visible**,you can use ***glPointSize(float size)*** or ***glPointSize(int size)*** like this:

```
gl.glPointSize(5.0f);
gl.glDrawElements(...);
```

And on the other hand,OpenGL ES 2.0 support Point Sprites and in vertex shader, you can set the size with gl_PointSize like this:

```
uniform float uThickness;
...
gl_PointSize = uThickness;
```

References:
[stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11095/opengl-es-2-0-point-sprites-size)
[wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/GLStart/Tut3)
Pro Open GL ES for Android